# Android Material Stepper - How to create ListView in Fragment?

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I am new to android Programming as well as Java, and right now I am making an app that requires a wizard. So, I am using a stepper library called Android Material Stepper by Stepstone.
In this wizard I have 3 step. the first step (First Fragment) contains an editText where the user fill in some text with certain pattern.  The text then passed to the second step (Second Fragment), where in this step the editText is split and convert to an array and display it to the end user as a ListView. Now here is the problem, I can't figure out how to do so.
This my second Fragment Code.

```
public class FragmentStep2 extends Fragment implements BlockingStep{TextView stepContent;
private DataManager dataManager;
onProceedListener onProceedListener;
private String passedData;

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context)
{
    super.onAttach(context);
    // TODO: Implement this method
    if(context instanceof onProceedListener | context instanceof DataManager) {
        onProceedListener = (onProceedListener) context;
        dataManager = (DataManager) context;
    } else {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Activity must implement OnProceedListener");
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.quick_lfl_step2, container, false);
    return v;
}

@Override
public void onSelected()
{
    // TODO: Implement this method
    passedData = dataManager.getData();
    String[] arrayLfl = passedData.split("@");
    ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.quick_lfl_row, R.id.absenLflList, arrayLfl);
    ListView listView = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.list_lfl);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}}
```

here is a logcat

> 06-03 19:53:03.925 I/ActivityManager(802): Displayed
>   tk.divabyan.ig/.activity.DefaultTabsActivity: +188ms (total
>   +35m19s326ms) 06-03 19:53:10.246 E/AndroidRuntime(2162): Process: tk.divabyan.ig, PID: 2162 06-03 19:53:10.246 E/AndroidRuntime(2162):
>     at
>   tk.divabyan.ig.activity.QuickLfl.FragmentStep2.onSelected(FragmentStep2.java:76)
>   06-03 19:53:10.246 E/AndroidRuntime(2162):    at
>   tk.divabyan.ig.activity.FragmentStep1.onNextClicked(FragmentStep1.java:68)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem is because I give a wrong resource id to the list adapter.